# how can i optimize performance with this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, users, activities and purchases.

Users has many activities and purchases, activities has 4 types.

I need to query users like this:

```
[
    {
        user_id: 1,

        // from activities
        post_count: 2,
        updated_count: 3,
        print_count: 4,
        share_count: 5,

        // from purchases
        purchase_count: 6
    },
    ...
]
```

I use this sql:

```
SELECT u.id, post.post_count, updated.update_count, print.print_count, share.share_count, purchase.purchase_count

FROM users as u

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, activity_type, count(*) as post_count 
  FROM activities 
  WHERE activity_type = 1
  GROUP BY user_id
  ) post

ON u.id = post.user_id

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, activity_type, count(*) as update_count
  FROM activities 
  WHERE activity_type = 2
  GROUP BY user_id
  ) updated

ON u.id = updated.user_id

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, activity_type, count(*) as print_count 
  FROM activities 
  WHERE activity_type = 3
  GROUP BY user_id
  ) print

ON u.id = print.user_id

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, activity_type, count(*) as share_count 
  FROM activities 
  WHERE activity_type = 4
  GROUP BY user_id
  ) share

ON u.id = share.user_id


LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, count(*) AS purchase_count 
  FROM purchases 
  GROUP BY user_id
  ) purchase

ON u.id = purchase.user_id
```

how can i optimize performance with this query?

---

Great thanks to [Eugen Rieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100552/eugen-rieck)

I modified his query to this, then it works.

```
SELECT
  users.id AS user_id,
  SUM(IF((activities.activity_type=1),1,0)) AS post_count,
  SUM(IF((activities.activity_type=2),1,0)) AS update_count,
  SUM(IF((activities.activity_type=3),1,0)) AS print_count,
  SUM(IF((activities.activity_type=4),1,0)) AS share_count,
  IFNULL(purchase.count,0) AS purchase_count
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN activities ON activities.user_id=users.id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) AS count 
    FROM purchases 
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) purchase
  ON users.id = purchase.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: First find out where your query is slow and then add appropriate indexes.  Look at the execution plan to determine which query or queries is taking the most time.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is your friend. Use it often, learn how to read the results, and how to fix issues that it notes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you run the activities table 4 times - this could be folded into one:

```
SELECT
  users.id AS user_id,
  SUM(IF(activites.activity_type=1,1,0)) AS post_count,
  SUM(IF(activites.activity_type=2,1,0)) AS update_count,
  SUM(IF(activites.activity_type=3,1,0)) AS print_count,
  SUM(IF(activites.activity_type=4,1,0)) AS share_count,
  IFNULL(COUNT(purchases.id),0) AS purchase_count
FROM
  users
  INNER JOIN activities ON activities.user_id=users.id
  LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.user_id=users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But you query return only one user like this:
`
[
  {
    user_id: 7,
    post_count: 15346,
    ...
  }
]
`

Comment: I forgot the GROUP BY clause - last line

Comment: Great thanks to you! I modified your query to `SELECT
  users.id AS user_id, purchase.purchase_count,
  SUM(IF((activities.activity_type=1),1,0)) AS post_count,
  SUM(IF((activities.activity_type=2),1,0)) AS update_count,
  SUM(IF((activities.activity_type=3),1,0)) AS print_count,
  SUM(IF((activities.activity_type=4),1,0)) AS share_count
FROM
  users
  INNER JOIN activities ON activities.user_id=users.id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) AS purchase_count 
    FROM purchases 
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) purchase
  ON users.id = purchase.user_id
GROUP BY users.id`, then it works!